# Wait until user has stopped typing in ComboBox to run macro (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I'm programming a sort of cross-reference database. An ID is generated based on the document name chosen or created.

The ComboBox I've referred to in the title acts on change (after 3 letters), checks the database for similar entries to what was typed, and displays the drop downof options that match. Once an entry is picked from the match list or a new name created - the appropriate number is generated.

Since the DropDown list is generated after every letter is typed, it takes a while to type what you want. I want to wait a few seconds after the *last* change to run the macro.

Any Ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Comment: How is the DropDown list generated? Have a look at the `DoEvents` command and also, you could change the `ComboBox` `Change` event to the `Exit` Event

Comment: It will help to see your code. I suspect you want something like what happens when you start typing in google search? If that's the case, consider importing the column from your database into an XML prior to user interaction with the field (i.e. at form load or workbook open). You can achieve the dropdown options list a lot more efficiently then. I have created something like this before but I used threading. Unfortunately, to my knowledge, you don't have the option to thread in VBA

Comment: Very similar to a google search yes. I wish I could start a separate thread. My code is long and I'm not sure posting it will be helpful in gathering ideas.  I'll put a short pseudo up though. I have not explored using a .xml and will do some research, but that would only shorten the amount of time of loading between letters, I want to avoid running the code all together.

Comment: Tom, my backup plan is to use LoseFocus but it deviates from the UE I was aiming for. I want it to show results as you type, because you may not know the exact wording of the desired title.

Comment: May be [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46406042/1726522) can help you, or at least give a hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit tricky as VBA doesn't support multi-threading. But we can use the `Application.OnTime` event to trigger a test in the future to test if the last key event is at least 3 seconds ago.

In a **Module** insert:

```
Option Explicit

Public LastKeyEvent As Date
Public Const WaitTimeValue As String = "00:00:03" 'test for key event in 3 seconds

Public Sub TestKeyEvent()
    'test if last key event is at least 3 seconds ago. 
    'If so: run your search or message box 
    'If not: do nothing
    If LastKeyEvent <> 0 And LastKeyEvent + TimeValue(WaitTimeValue) <= Now Then
        LastKeyEvent = 0 'Ensure this is only triggered once:
                         'If we don't do this and multiple keys are pressed within 1 second 
                         'then it would run multiple times.

        MsgBox "3 seconds without keypress, we can start search"
        'start your search here (instead of message box) …
    End If
End Sub
```

Now you can use for your textbox change event eg `TextBox1`:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_Change()
    Dim alertTime As Date

    LastKeyEvent = Now 'remember when the last key event was
    alertTime = LastKeyEvent + TimeValue(WaitTimeValue)
    Application.OnTime alertTime, "TestKeyEvent" 'run TestKeyEvent in 3 seconds
End Sub
```

> **Note:**
>   This is a workaround that works for 2 or more seconds. But does not for less then 2 seconds.

Comment: YES! I've tested and this is perfect Peh, someday I hope to be as smart as you. Cant thank you enough for the quick answer.

Comment: @EndUserAbuser If it fits your needs, please mark answer as "accepted". Thats the way we say "Thank you" here... :)

Comment: ha It took me longer than it should have but I finally found the green check, thanks for the tip.

Comment: The note is correct, I started running into issues where the sub was not being started (intermittently), if I change it back to 2 it runs every-time. That's good info @Peh

Answer (score 2):

An alternative using `Application.OnTime` again:

In **Userform**:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_KeyPress(ByVal KeyAscii As MSForms.ReturnInteger)
    StartTimer
End Sub
```

In **Module**:

```
Public RunTime As Double

Public Sub StartTimer()
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=RunTime, Procedure:="YourCode", Schedule:=False
    RunTime = Now() + TimeValue("00:00:03")
    Application.OnTime RunTime, "YourCode"
End Sub

Public Sub YourCode()
    MsgBox "It's working!"
End Sub
```